# Out of memory on a 5898256-byte allocation when using Picasso Libarary

Tags: android, out-of-memory, picasso

```
03-11 10:19:12.894 1904-2250/com.baiaphoto.android E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 5898256-byte allocation.
03-11 10:19:12.894 1904-2250/com.baiaphoto.android I/dalvikvm: "Picasso-/storage/emulated/0/baiaphotos/image-default.png" prio=5 tid=21 RUNNABLE
03-11 10:19:12.894 1904-2250/com.baiaphoto.android I/dalvikvm:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4392a8d0 self=0x68b9a888
03-11 10:19:12.894 1904-2250/com.baiaphoto.android I/dalvikvm:   | sysTid=2250 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1755348024
03-11 10:19:12.894 1904-2250/com.baiaphoto.android I/dalvikvm:   | state=R schedstat=( 1923135000 790241000 935 ) utm=187 stm=5 core=0
03-11 10:19:12.894 1904-2250/com.baiaphoto.android I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
03-11 10:19:12.894 1904-2250/com.baiaphoto.android I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:620)
03-11 10:19:12.894 1904-2250/com.baiaphoto.android I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
03-11 10:19:12.894 1904-2250/com.baiaphoto.android I/dalvikvm:     at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.decodeStream(BitmapHunter.java:142)
03-11 10:19:12.894 1904-2250/com.baiaphoto.android I/dalvikvm:     at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:217)
03-11 10:19:12.894 1904-2250/com.baiaphoto.android I/dalvikvm:     at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:159)
03-11 10:19:12.894 1904-2250/com.baiaphoto.android I/dalvikvm:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
03-11 10:19:12.894 1904-2250/com.baiaphoto.android I/dalvikvm:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-11 10:19:12.894 1904-2250/com.baiaphoto.android I/dalvikvm:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-11 10:19:12.894 1904-2250/com.baiaphoto.android I/dalvikvm:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-11 10:19:12.894 1904-2250/com.baiaphoto.android I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-11 10:19:12.894 1904-2250/com.baiaphoto.android I/dalvikvm:     at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run(Utils.java:411)
```

Comment: You ran out of memory.  Look at what's using your memory via hprofs, and figure out if you have a leak.  If so, fix it.  If not, reduce your total memory usage for the app.  If you're using a lot of Bitmaps, use a cache and don't hold them all in memory.

Comment: Picasso cache your downlaoded images by default. you can write code using to tell picasso not to cache images/data.

Comment: this error appears when your available memory size gets low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible to say what the problem is without seeing exact code, but have you tried .fit() or resize while loading the image with Picasso into your ImageView? I was having a similar problem with running out of memory while loading many (large) images in a RecyclerView and this fixed it.

For example:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imageURL).fit().into(exampleImageView);
```

[More examples/explanation about re-sizing and scaling with Picasso](https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit)